# How can I get the EF Core model configuration entity property comment set in HasComment as the html title attribute

Tags: entity-framework-core, modelmetadata, ef-model-builder

Trying to set the title attribute of an html element as the parameter passed to the entity.Property().HasComment(comment) method.

I've tried with no luck:

```
<label asp-for="OrganizationTypeId" title="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.Description">
```

The value is null while the OnModelCreating method is setting the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Organization>(entity =>
{
   entity.Property(e => e.OrganizationTypeId).HasComment("Foreign key of the Org...");
```

Is this comment available to be used as an html attribute?

Thanks

Comment: See [the following](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/ef-core-find-csharp/blob/master/EntityCoreExtensions/DbContexts.cs#L70) DbContext extension method  which shows how to retrieve comments for a model but does provide a full path to displaying comments. The [following](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/NorthWind-2020/blob/master/North/Forms/PropertyGetCommentForm.cs) shows usage in a windows form (yeah it's not ASP.NET) but gives an idea how to get comments for a model. Should be enough to work into your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This DbContext extension method](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/ef-core-find-csharp/blob/master/EntityCoreExtensions/DbContexts.cs#L70) shows how to retrieve comments for a model.

Comment: The answer will not work with `EF Core 6` as there were changes made on how to get comments, see the version of EF Core 6 [here](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/ef-core-6-tips/blob/master/EntityFrameworkCoreHelpers/EntityExtensions.cs#L93:L113)